# How to clean up branch after wrong commit + baseless merge

Tags: tfs

A while ago I deleted a folder "Data" by error, and commited. Asking my senior developper what to do he said "I'll just add the files again" which in hindsight was the wrong choice. TFS regards these files as 2 different files so when we merged we got conflicts. In a stroke of genius another developer (who was doing the merge) decided to rename all the old files and then merged. This was 6 months ago and seeped through all our child branches.

Now we have a couple of branches with the following files

**Parent branch**
Actor.csv 
Actor.csv.old

**Child branch**
Actor.csv 
Actor.csv.old

I've solved the merging errors by doing a baseless merge between (parent branch) actor.csv.old to (child) actor.csv and (parent) actor.csv to (child) actor.csv

But now the folder is littered with .old files. How do I get rid of these? Merge the .csv file with .csv.old file? Delete the .csv.old file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we just struggled through it. We deleted the .old files but then it would also delete the original files (since they were linked I'm guessing). Then after that delete we undeleted them and then merged. Problem solved. .old files were deleted and we were able to merge.